# does mbsync know i deleted folders?

Tags: mutt, imap, offlineimap

Newly working with `neomutt` and `mbsync`.  I did an initial grab of all my mail and folders which was fine.

Then I started organizing my folders and mail.  Some of the folders (or "mailboxes") within the account were cleaned up and DELETED.

When I run `mbsync -a` it seems to want to find those deleted folders.  The error message is as follows:

```
Error: channel example@gmail.com: far side box INBOX/subscribed cannot be opened.
```

The `INBOX/subscribed` is a folder that no longer exists under `INBOX`

Yet, the `mbsync` task is still trying to fetch it.

**Is there a config file somewhere that needs updating? What can I do to fix this error?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably solved this by now, but for future travellers:

`mbsync --remove-near` will attempt to remove near-side mailboxes that are gone from the far side.

`mbsync` will refuse to remove near-side mailboxes which are empty and will complain with:

`Warning: channel <your channel>: far side box <mailbox> cannot be opened and near side box <mailbox> is not empty.`

You can manually remove (or move out of your maildir store) any near-side folders and re-run with `--remove-near` until everything is synced, then you can sync how you normally would.

I'm quite new to `mbsync` so I'm not sure which options in my `mbsyncrc` are relevant, but I have these set:

```
Patterns *
Create Both
SyncState *
Expunge Both
```

You might want to read up on those settings if yours differ and the above doesn't work.